# Diagonal corner to corner divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to design a web page like the following. I am more of a back end programmer but have wanted to learn more about design to be able to build attractive sites. I am looking to have 7 diagonal divs(for each color of rainbow) in the corner that look like I have below. The text right now just represents what background color it will be. These divs would be links to load page data. I would like the text inside each to be diagonal as well and I think I can do that with text rotation.

Any Help in this matter would be greatly appreciated and also if you guys know of some great resources to learn how to build attractive web pages in html,css,jquery that would be great. I get the syntax I just don't know how to take a blank canvas and make it beautiful yet. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What support does your project need to have? There are ways of doing this with CSS that will only be supported by more modern browsers. There are other alternatives that are more backwards compatible, but also much more time consuming to implement!

Comment: If you're only supporting modern browsers it'd be best to use (the prefixed version of) `transform:rotate(-45deg);` and then position them absolutely where you want. You'd apply it to both the rectangles and the text within them

Comment: Yes, I am not looking to support those old browsers. This is mainly for me to build something I think will be a cool design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to CSS3, this is just a proof of concept. Don't expect IE8 to support this! http://jsfiddle.net/TreeTree/fyySn/7/

```
body {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;
}

.rainbow {
    width:500px;
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin:0% 0%;
    -ms-transform-origin:0% 0%;
    -moz-transform-origin:0% 0%;
    -webkit-transform-origin:0% 0%;
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;
    left:-150px;
}

.rainbow div {
    height:40px;
    text-align:center;

}

div a {
    line-height:40px;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:20px;
}
```

Edit: This is a way cleaner solution. Instead of transforming each bar, I transform the container.

Comment: How would I get text to show up in the divs? I tried putting it in the div and a tag in the fiddle and it wouldn't show up.

Comment: You'd use `div a { position:absolute; bottom:0;` then the appropriate `left` value for each div. http://jsfiddle.net/fyySn/5/

Comment: @BrentMoses I have updated with a way better solution to my original.

Comment: I like your version bfred. What is causing the red section to come away from the edge.

Comment: It's just a matter of tweaking the `left` and `top` properties until you get it the way you want.

Comment: Check out http://jsfiddle.net/yEV4P/ for the complete fiddle. I think this will help some people out. Thanks.